# Overclocking graphics card?

Tags: drivers, 14.04, intel-graphics, overclocking

I have a Intel® Iris™ Pro Graphics 5200 on Ubuntu14.04 (64 bit). Is there any kind of way I can overclock the card successfully and if so how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully overclocked my Nvidia under Ubuntu. Have to experience with Intel graphics under Linux, but found this after googling: http://blog.ffwll.ch/2013/03/overclocking-your-intel-gpu-on-linux.html